# optimize this code: python list iter for comparing 2 lists

Tags: python, list, loops, python-itertools

```
def cross(listMaster, listSlave, criteria="email"):
    if criteria == "email":
        emailListSlave = []
        returnUnique = []

        for item in listSlave: 
            emailListSlave.append(item[2]) #appends emails

        for no,item in enumerate(listMaster):
            if no % 10000 == 0: 
                print("Status: {percent:.2f} %".format(percent=(no/len(listMaster))))

            if item[2] not in emailListSlave:
                returnUnique.append(item)

        return returnUnique
```

I have 2 lists: listMaster and listSlave. 
Both of these lists have a about 2,000,000 items which themselves have about 24 items within. My goal is to "sort" the lists by the third element in the list, which happens to be an email. And then I want to find unique emails between the Master and Slave list. So if the Slave list has an email present in the Master list, then throw out that item and continue.

My algo:

1) load the 3rd element of each item in the Slave list (email) into a new list (emailListSlave)

2) iterate over the MasterList and check if the third element of each item in the MasterList is in the emailListSlave

3) if 2 is True then continue, if false then append the returnUnique list with unique emails found only in listMaster

Running this is EXTREMELY slow. I managed to get 10% done in about 20 minutes. Can I speed up this process perhaps with iter? itertools? Please help me optimize this code.

Comment: To format your code correctly, copy-paste your code into the question box, then select everything you pasted (including the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K or the button in the UI with the braces on it.

Comment: Have you checked out `set`? Pass in the list you want to eliminate duplicates from like this `set(list_with_duplicates)`.

Comment: I misread the question, but this is still a set operation. Check out set difference: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's so slow is that the search is in linear time. Use a dictionary with the key being your search string. Should make lots of difference.

Comment: This isn't actually linear time, it's O(n^2) (or exponential) as the search function is O(n) while the iteration over the original list is O(n) as well.  What he needs to do is build a dictionary with the emails in the master list, then iterate over the slave list and check for existence in the map.  This would effective make it linear time or O(n) to do the whole thing.  This is going to be much faster than the originally proposed algorithm.

Comment: Yes, sorry, wasn't clear I was talking about the inner search loop.

Comment: Gotcha.  Your suggestion to use a hash-based solution was definitely correct though.

Comment: It's my fault, I shouldn't have rushed. Your explanation is far more detailed anyway 

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Here is your solution...

```
def cross(listMaster, listSlave, criteria="email"):
    if criteria == "email":
        returnUnique = listMaster[:]  # create a copy of the master list
        emails_in_master = set()

        for item in listMaster:
            emails_in_master.add(item[2])  # add the master emails to the set

        for item in listSlave:
            if item[2] in emails_in_master:
                returnUnique.append(item)

        return returnUnique
```

Your algorithm is O(n^2) because you are looping over a list, then searching another list per iteration of the above.  This results in exponential runtime, which is basically the worst you can get.  You need to try to get the algorithm to linear complexity in order to have a decent runtime.

Your algorithm is basically the following:

```
loop for n:                             # this costs n
    loop for n:                         # this costs n for each of the n's above
         add an item or continue        # so total, this is O(n * n)
```

What you want is the following:

```
loop for n:                             # this costs n
    build a lookup

loop for n:                             # this costs n
    add item if in lookup or continue   # so total, this is O(n)
```

I generated test data into CSV's on my local machine.  Here is how I created the CSV's...

```
>>> import csv
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> fake = Faker()
>>> with open('masters.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
...     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
...     for i in range(20000):
...         writer.writerow([fake.name(), fake.address(), fake.email(), fake.job(), fake.ssn()])
...
>>> with open('slaves.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
...     writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
...     for i in range(20000):
...         writer.writerow([fake.name(), fake.address(), fake.email(), fake.job(), fake.ssn()])
...
```

Once those were generated (note there were 20k per file, as 2 million would have taken too long to generate), I built the following test suite to compare the different approaches...

```
import csv
import unittest

email = lambda l: l[2]


class TestListComparison(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.masters = []
        cls.slaves = []

        with open('masters.csv', 'rb') as master_csv:
            reader = csv.reader(master_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            cls.masters = list(reader)

        with open('slaves.csv', 'rb') as slave_csv:
            reader = csv.reader(slave_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            cls.slaves = list(reader)

    def test_make_sure_lists_are_well_formed(self):
        self.assertEqual(len(self.masters), len(self.slaves))
        self.assertEqual(len(self.masters), 20000)

    def test_list_combination_original(self):
        emailListSlave = []
        returnUnique = []

        for item in self.slaves:
            emailListSlave.append(email(item))

        for no, item in enumerate(self.masters):  # O(n)
            if email(item) not in self.slaves:    # O(n)
                returnUnique.append(item)         # O(1)

        # Total complexity: O(n * n * 1) => O(n^2)        

    def test_list_combination_using_lookup(self):
        lookup = set()
        returnUnique = self.masters[:]     # create a copy of masters list

        for master in self.masters:        # loop over the master list O(n)
            lookup.add(email(master))      # add the email to the set  O(1)

        for slave in self.slaves:          # loop over the list again  O(n)
            if email(slave) in lookup:     # check the lookup          O(1)
                returnUnique.append(slave) # add the item to the list  O(1)

        # Total complexity: O(n + n) => O(2n) => O(n)
```

Here are the runtime results:

[image: test comparison]

Note that the lookup test took about 15ms while the original algorithm took around 14s.  Thats quite a few orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: that last image, what program did you use to run those tests?

Comment: It was PyCharm by JetBrains.  It’s amazing.  It’s the best python IDE hands down.